# CSS3 animation: inactive, active and additional 'end' state?

Tags: css, hover, state, css-animations

I have a button with an animated background on hover. It fills with a coloured background from left to right, however currently on mouse out it reverses the animation; the colour shrinks back toward the left and disappears. On mouse out I would like the fill to continue moving from left to right, so that it disappears out the right of the button. Any ideas? An example of this can be seen on the 'VISIT WEBSITE' button here:

http://www.notashop.com.au/new/project/lifewithbird/

Ideally would like to do this using CSS3 animation, however im feeling the active/inactive state of css3 animation may be the limiting factor here. If it cant be done using CSS3 any ideas using jQuery? A jsfiddle would be much appreciated!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ready for something cool... You will need to make this multi browser friendly but thats easy.
THis is ready in ff

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/W6a7C/1/)

```
.button {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative;

}

.button:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    content: "";
    height: 45px;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.button:hover:before{
    -webkit-animation: left 1s;
  -moz-animation:    left 1s;
  -o-animation:      left 1s;
  animation:         left 1s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.button p{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 2
}
@keyframes left {
    0% {left: -100%;}
    50% {animation-play-state: paused; }
    100%{left: 0%; animation-play-state: paused;}
}
```

Your gonna have allot of questions...

Comment: Did you look at it in Firefox?

Comment: Sorry did not see your 'ready in FF' comment. Thanks so much Cam! Looks great

Comment: I am struggling to know how to make it work in GC and other browsers however? Do they all support keyframes? What is making this work in FF but tripping the others up (you seemed to know that it wouldn't work in others, hoping you know what area needs to be worked on?)

Comment: Yes they do, you have to incorporate the -o- -moz- and -webkit